# How to read two concatenated JSON files?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the follwing file consising of two concatendated JSON strings:

```
{
  "hello": 2,
  "world": 3
}{
  "something": 5,
  "else": 6
}
```

Both of them are correct individually (they are more complex than that, but are always two JSON dicts one after each other).

Since I can predict the format of the first one (close to my example above), I will parse the file with a regex expression and end up separating them (I just need the second JSON):

```
{[\s\S]*?}([.\n]*?)
```

While this solution works, I wanted to make sure that there is not a more generic way to address this problem.

Comment: if it's always }{, then simply  my_string.replace('}{', '},{') and then json.loads(my_string), as it should now be valid.

Comment: @Artagel: this is a brilliant idea, thanks. Care to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Sure, I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply format your string by converting it to a valid python object like a list of dictionary then load it with json module:

```
In [60]: s = """{
  "hello": 2,
  "world": 3
}{
  "something": 5,
  "else": 6
}"""

In [61]: json.loads("[{}]".format(s.replace('}{', '},{')))
Out[61]: [{'hello': 2, 'world': 3}, {'something': 5, 'else': 6}]
```

Comment: This mangles data if "}{" is inside strings.

Answer (score 18):

[`raw_decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode) will parse a string and return its object plus the index where the object serialization ended. As long as the document fits in memory reasonably, you can just nibble away at the string.

```
text="""{
  "hello": 2,
  "world": 3
}{
  "something": 5,
  "else": 6
}

"""
import json
decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
text = text.lstrip() # decode hates leading whitespace
while text:
    obj, index = decoder.raw_decode(text)
    text = text[index:].lstrip()
    print(obj)
```

```
{'world': 3, 'hello': 2}
{'else': 6, 'something': 5}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
my_str = """{
  "hello": 2,
  "world": 3
}{
  "something": 5,
  "else": 6
}"""

fixed_str = my_str.replace('}{', '},{')

my_json = json.loads("[" + fixed_str + "]")
```

Comment: This mangles data if "}{" is inside strings.