# Extract json objects from file

Tags: python, json

I have a problem extracting objects from a json file.

Json file is like:

```
{
  "name": "AIMT",
  "deltas": [
    -0.44,
    0.33
  ],
  "deltassum": 0,
  "deltatot": 3.3492659160366145,
  "voltot": 102120.0,
  "cmfs": [
    -0.75,
    -0.4458
  ],
  "volps": [
    2578.0,
    4005.0
  ],
  "opens": [
    18.34,
    18.07
  ],
  "tailsnoses": [
    -0.37,
    -0.63
  ],
  "fms": [
    -0.75,
    -0.25
  ],
  "resist": [
    -0.25,
    -0.63
  ],
  "mktcap": "",
  "avgvolume": ""
}
{
  "name": "GOLD",
  "deltas": [
    -0.18,
    0.52.........
```

My code is :

```
with open('tickersjson2-200427') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for p in data['name']:
        print(data['name'])
```

The code that create the json file is:

```
with open('tickersjson2', 'w') as f:
                for x in ticks:
                            f.write(json.dumps(x.__dict__))
            f.close()
```

I want to extract each object and store it in a list with all its related data.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thats not valid JSON. Theres no comma separating the objects and are the objects in an array? Can you show what your output should be like?

Comment: I would like a list of tickers objects (pkl objects is fine) with each object having as attribute (name, deltas[], volps[], etc...). In other words, I'd like to convert this file in pkl objects. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I already have the objects defined.

Comment: Maybe the listake from my code that creates the json file:
```with open('tickersjson2', 'w') as f:
                for x in ticks:
                            f.write(json.dumps(x.__dict__))
            f.close()````

Comment: There should be a comma between each of your objects in your json.  You could possibly just dump ticks as a whole into your json file instead of iterating through it. When you have valid json data you pretty much want it as it is? instead of `for p in data['name']`, which is you trying to loop over an object, just use `for p in data:` then each p is a python dict.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read two concatenated JSON files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985544/how-to-read-two-concatenated-json-files)